# What is the jQuery code to Expand a Read More?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have many paragraphs on a single page. Each paragraph is for a different author with a read more. If they click on the read more or within the paragraph I would like to hide/fade all the other paragraphs out and expand the one they clicked on.

What is the jQuery code for doing something like this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could use accordion of jQueryUI http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: We'd probably need a small code sample but Sotiris and dragon are right - use an accordion or other plugin.  You'll save time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it without adding any markup to your paragraphs.

The HTML:

```
​<div id="content">
  <p>content_here</p>
  <p>content_here</p>
  <p>content_here</p>
  <p>content_here</p>
​</div>​​​​​​​
```

And you'll want some css like this:

```
.dorsal { display: none; }
```

Next, the JavaScript:

```
​$('#content').find('p').html( function(){ // for every paragraph in container
   var exposer = '<a href="#" class="expose">More...</a>', // link to insert
       content = $(this).html().split(''),
       cutLength = 50, // choose the cutoff point
       anterior = content.slice( 0,cutLength ).join(''),
       dorsal = content.slice( cutLength ).join(''),
       joined = 
           anterior 
         + exposer 
         + '<span class="dorsal">' 
         + dorsal 
         + '</span>'; // assemble the new contents
    return joined;
})
.on('click','.expose',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $thisp = $(this).closest('p');
   $('#content').find('p').not( $thisp ).hide(); // hide others
   $thisp             // for the enclosing paragraph
     .find('.dorsal') // select the hidden piece
     .show()          // show it
     .end()           // back to the paragraph
     .find('.expose') // find the "show more" link
     .hide();         // hide it
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You'll need this in your `$(document).ready()` handler.

As others point out, there are many plugins to do this kind of thing. Sometimes it's useful to work it out yourself, though.

Re-collapsing and exposing the original paragraphs is left as an exercise.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/wAY8g/1/

---

**Updated** to support multiple paragraph groups, per Ibanez's comment:

```
$('#content').find('div').prepend(function() {
  var exposer = '<a href="#" class="expose">More...</a>',
    rawcontent = $(this).text(),
    cutLength = 100,
    abstract = rawcontent.split('').slice(0, cutLength).join(''),
    abbreviated = '<span class="abstract">' + abstract + exposer + '</span>';
  return abbreviated;
}).end().on('click', '.expose', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $thisgroup = $(this).closest('div');
    $('#content').children('div').not($thisgroup).hide(); // hide others
    $thisgroup
      .find('p').show()
      .parent()
      .append('<a href="#" class="showall">Show all</a>')
      .end()
      .closest('div').find('.abstract').hide();
}).on('click', '.showall', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('#content').find('div').show().end()
        .find('p:visible').hide().end()
        .find('.abstract').show();
});​
```

For this to work, we now start with all paragraphs hidden via css, and the script builds and displays the abstracts on load. Also updated to provide links to re-show the original state.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRB92/1/

Comment: Ken, this only works because you have one paragraph per topic. See what happens when you add more paragraphs per topic.

Comment: @Ibanez, I agree, but your question stipulates the narrow case of only one paragraph per author. As you imply, there would have to be an additional container around each "story" if you want to handle groups of multiple paragraphs. After all, how would the code know which paragraphs constitute a group? An extra layer of grouping also adds to the challenge, since you'll have to create a shorter visible extract without breaking on the enclosed paragraph structure.

Comment: @Ibanez, We're going down the rabbit hole a bit here, but I've updated the example to allow paragraphs to be grouped by container divs.

Comment: Ken, This is very close to what I am looking for. I see a few problems that are not working with my layout. I start each paragraph with an image of the personal and a drop cap for the first letter of the paragraph. I'm losing the image and the span tag for the drop cap until it is clicked on. I also would like to know how you can change where the cutLength happens. It's cutting words off without completing the word. Is there a way to tell it where to do the cut and make it at different points for each paragraph? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ibanez, There are simplifications here since it only illustrates a general approach. First, the "abstract" is built using the plain text of each section (see `rawcontent`). That's why your caps and other elements aren't in the abstract. As to respecting word boundaries -- that can indeed be done. You'd replace the static cutlength value with a function that inspects the candidate cut point, checks if it's a space, and if not, walks backward until finding a space; then returns that as the actual cut point. If you do all this, of course, you've basically written a full featured plugin.

Comment: Ken, if you did this it would be a great plugin. If I was able to do it, I would not be here asking for help. Thanks!

Comment: Ken, is there a way I can send you a link to the website that I'm trying to do this on? I don't want to make it public. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let this plugin handle the hard part for you:

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="sample_1">
    paragraph sample
    <br><a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="hide_all_pars('par_1')">read more</a>
    <div id="par_1" style="display: none;">
       Whole paragraph
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sample_2">
    paragraph sample 2
    <br><a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="hide_all_pars('par_2')">read more</a>
   <div id="par_2" style="display: none;">
       Whole paragraph 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hide_all_pars(par){
        var i=0;            
        for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
            $('#par_'+i).fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('#'+par).fadeIn('slow');
    }
</script>
```

the 2 in the for loop would be replaced with how many parahgraphs you have

Comment: This is not what I had in mind. Your example only expands the paragraph and pushes down the other authors below it.

Comment: Sorry I haven't understood your question then :) maybe some one else can help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this because the above didn't do exactly what I wanted. This is some jQuery code that adds read more to sections with at least 1 paragraph. It allows for other elements like headings.  It is designed to hide the content after the first paragraph or if the 1st paragraph is long it chops that paragraph at a defined point. It also has minimise buttons.

```js
if ($('.contentDiv').find('p').length) {

  $(".contentDiv").each(function(i) {

    var splitFirstPara = '300';
    var maxFirstParaLength = '350';
    var firstPara = $(this).find('p').first().text();
    var firstParaLength = firstPara.length;


    if (firstParaLength > maxFirstParaLength) {

      var frontSentence = firstPara.split('').slice(0, splitFirstPara).join('');
      var endSentence = firstPara.split('').slice(splitFirstPara, ).join('');
      var newSentence = '<p>' + frontSentence + '<button class="readMore" data-toggleShow="' + i + '">read more...</button><span class="toggleShow" data-toggleShow="' + i + '" style="display:none;">' + endSentence + '</span></p>';

      $(this).find('p').first().replaceWith(newSentence);
      $(this).find('p').first().nextAll().addClass('toggleShow').attr('data-toggleshow', i).hide();

    } else {

      $(this).find('p').first().nextAll().addClass('toggleShow').attr('data-toggleshow', i).hide();
      $(this).find('p').first().after('<button class="readMore" data-toggleShow="' + i + '">read more</button>');

    }

    $(this).append('<button class="minimise" data-toggleShow="' + i + '" style="display:none;">minimise</button>');

  });

  $("button.readMore").click(function() {

    var sameSectionItems = $(this).attr('data-toggleshow');

    $(this).hide();
    $('.toggleShow[data-toggleshow="' + sameSectionItems + '"]').fadeIn();
    $('.minimise[data-toggleshow="' + sameSectionItems + '"]').fadeIn();


  });

  $("button.minimise").click(function() {

    var sameSectionItems = $(this).attr('data-toggleshow');

    $(this).hide();
    $('.toggleShow[data-toggleshow="' + sameSectionItems + '"]').fadeOut();
    $('.readMore[data-toggleshow="' + sameSectionItems + '"]').fadeIn();

  });

}
```

```css
.container {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

button.minimise,
button.readMore {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p>button.readMore {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="contentDiv">
      <h2>Heading Section 1</h2>
      <h3>The first paragraph below is long, <br/>so the read more chops the paragraph and puts the 'read more' inline.</h3>
      <p>I'm baby air plant scenester humblebrag stumptown, banh mi godard shaman fanny pack waistcoat retro cred hoodie messenger bag blue bottle etsy. Pabst plaid literally craft beer actually coloring book vegan shoreditch flannel kickstarter pork belly
        man braid celiac twee intelligentsia. Activated charcoal food truck raw denim, normcore ennui gentrify disrupt salvia brunch lo-fi air plant literally vice iceland woke. Plaid woke knausgaard trust fund thundercats glossier. Schlitz tilde tumblr
        bespoke chartreuse health goth wolf selvage. Retro iceland ethical, gastropub shoreditch four loko 8-bit roof party direct trade.</p>
      <p>Palo santo ethical health goth, affogato neutra you probably haven't heard of them small batch echo park photo booth man braid. Food truck godard beard shaman austin jianbing hot chicken XOXO af mumblecore pork belly meditation. Kickstarter brooklyn
        VHS DIY man bun. Retro venmo fanny pack banjo post-ironic.</p>
      <p>Normcore art party vaporware, jianbing austin truffaut succulents lyft slow-carb wolf bitters. Lo-fi shaman microdosing hashtag. Offal church-key pickled fingerstache tacos subway tile XOXO whatever yr. Ethical drinking vinegar readymade irony,
        marfa offal kickstarter.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentDiv">
      <h2>Heading Section 2</h2>
      <p>Palo santo ethical health goth, affogato neutra you probably haven't heard of them small batch echo park photo booth man braid. Food truck godard beard shaman austin jianbing hot chicken XOXO af mumblecore pork belly meditation. Kickstarter brooklyn
        VHS DIY man bun. Retro venmo fanny pack banjo post-ironic.</p>
      <p>Normcore art party vaporware, jianbing austin truffaut succulents lyft slow-carb wolf bitters. Lo-fi shaman microdosing hashtag. Offal church-key pickled fingerstache tacos subway tile XOXO whatever yr. Ethical drinking vinegar readymade irony,
        marfa offal kickstarter.</p>
      <p>Whatever hella hexagon, williamsburg artisan twee wayfarers palo santo shabby chic yr vice pickled wolf. DIY listicle food truck messenger bag lo-fi, la croix offal roof party flannel asymmetrical hoodie trust fund. Fingerstache YOLO messenger bag,
        photo booth shaman normcore iceland austin sartorial copper mug. Organic bespoke mlkshk readymade. XOXO cardigan neutra deep v scenester air plant venmo crucifix chambray gochujang brunch truffaut everyday carry vinyl banh mi.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```